# packing functions in class

Tags: python, class, object

I want to build class which give me:
input:

```
model = load('best_model.joblib')
model

output:
XGBRegressor(base_score=0.5, booster='gbtree', colsample_bylevel=1,
             colsample_bynode=1, colsample_bytree=1, gamma=0,
             importance_type='gain', learning_rate=0.1, max_delta_step=0,
             max_depth=3, min_child_weight=1, missing=nan, n_estimators=80,
             n_jobs=1, nthread=None, objective='reg:squarederror',
             random_state=0, reg_alpha=0, reg_lambda=1, scale_pos_weight=1,
             seed=None, silent=None, subsample=1, verbosity=1)
```

i have input:

```
class Using_model:
    # load best model
    def get_model():
        model = load('best_model.joblib')
        return model

Using_model.get_model

output:
<function __main__.Using_model.get_model()>
```

I have to build application by object programming where 1 function from my class will loading model from my hard drive
How can i build it ?

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke a function you must put round parrentheses at the end.

Eg:

```
Using_model.get_model()
```

What you get currently is the description of the function pointer, not the result of the function invocation.
Btw you do not need a class to invoke such a function.

Comment: Great solution. Thank you so much bro :) Best wishes